# How do i get the name of an article with is ID with the async way in Symfony2.8

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

Hi everyone i'm looking for a way to get the name of a product if the user write in a input the ID of the product

Here what i've done with JS

```
function showHint(str) {
  if (str.length == 13) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/sf/web/extranet_dev.php/plateforme/reassort_scan/'+str,
        dataType: "json",
        method: "POST",
        success: function(){
            var nomProduit = ...
            document.getElementById("designationModal").innerHTML = nomProduit;
        }
    });
}
```

But i don't know how to do with symfony to get the name of the product with the id (str) here's what i've try

```
/**
 *
 * @Route("reassort_scan/{code}", name="plateforme_reassort_scan")
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function reassortScanArticle(Request $request)
{
    $idArticle = intval($request->attributes->getInt('code'));
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $designation = $em
        ->createQuery("
            SELECT a.nom
            FROM Nalods\Entity\Article a
            WHERE a.articleGencod=".$idArticle
        )
    ;
    return $designation;
}
```

if someone can answer me i will be grateful ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution:

```
public function reassortScanArticle($code)
{
    $repo= $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('Nalods:Article');
    $designation = $repo->findByArticleGencod($code);
    return $designation;
}
```

Doctrine has magic methods and generates automatically 'finders' by fields names.

Comment: At the moment, le `articleGencod` is not the identifier of the entity.

Comment: then i need a function `findByArticleGencod`

Comment: No you dont. Read whole content. Also - if doctrine wouldnt make it for you its really not that difficult to create one in repository. Please, put some effort, at least a little ;-)

Comment: hmmm ok thank you very much but atm my `$articleGencod` is a 

`@var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection`
`@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ArticleGencod", mappedBy="article")`

so it will not work i guess